# Unity3D: Maximum size to movietexture www file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, movie, ogg

I have a question about Unity3D's movieTexture object.

In my current game, I have a 3D room that the player is sitting in, and there is a computer screen in front of him/her. I have a movietexture on this screen that autoplays a movie.

This movie is a link to the application's ####_data folder. It looks for anything called "movie.ogv"

I had this working with a 4-minute long video. It works **perfectly**.

So, I then converted an episode of a popular Tv show to OGG Theora, "ogv", and placed it in the same are under the same name. Now, when the game loads, everything is instantly black. I have to open the Task Manager to see that my game is frozen.

Does Unity have to...somehow process these larger files, and needs to freeze at a black screen for a while? Or does it just not like long videos?

The intented purpose is to allow users to throw in any movie file they want and watch it in-game. This purpose is defeated if Unity freaks right out when something that's only 22 minutes and around 150MB is placed inside. Help please? Any ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;



[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]

public class VideoScript : MonoBehaviour 

{   

    MovieTexture movieTexture;

    private bool isPaused;


    void Start ()   {


        isPaused = false;

        //WWW www = new WWW ("http://www.unity3d.com/webplayers/Movie/sample.ogg");   
        WWW www = new WWW ("file:///"+(Application.dataPath)+"/movie.ogv");   


        movieTexture = (MovieTexture) www.movie; 

        renderer.material.mainTexture = movieTexture;

        audio.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;



    }



    void Update ()  {

        if (movieTexture.isReadyToPlay && !movieTexture.isPlaying && !isPaused)
        { 

            movieTexture.Play(); 
            audio.Play();

        }



        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) 
        {
            if (movieTexture.isPlaying) 
            {
                movieTexture.Pause();
                isPaused=true;
            }

            else 

            {
                movieTexture.Play();
                isPaused=false;
            }
        }


    }   

}
```

Comment: The rule of thumb is to use proper tags so your question can be viewed by relevant expert groups. If you use a wrong tag, you can expect few or no reply at all. If you want to get more from SO, learn the rules, http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @DillonRobinson FWIW I, as a Unity user, follow the unity3d tag. If you mistag your question, I won't see it. And many of us won't, reducing your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: That said, does it hang/crash completely, or just for a very long time? Afaik there is no explicit limit to movie texture size, but big files can eat up a fair amount of resources. And what is the platform/hardware you're trying to run this on?

Comment: Hi Bart - 
I've never waited long enough to see, but I've waited at least 5 minutes before of just black. Then one time, it loaded a single frame of what my default camera sees, and then froze completely. I'm running this on Windows 7 64-bit. 8gb of RAM, i5 processor @ 3.30 GHz.

I just assumed though that, having the file included locally (the user adds it to the data folder), it wouldn't eat up too much resources to stream an existing file without having to download or buffer.

Comment: @Bart I think I was supposed to tag you in response - been a while since I commented here

Comment: I might have a look later on to see if I can reproduce it. It could perhaps help if you could create a project for me to download and try. Because there's plenty of stuff that I might not think off.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

You are missing one key line in your start script.

```
// Wait for download to complete
yield www;
```

It would take Unity a while to load the content of a larger file hence your script gets an empty movie texture.

Here is the complete Start script as it should be :

```
    void Start ()   
    {    

       isPaused = false;

       // This variable is defined outside of the Start function.         
       www = new WWW ("file:///"+(Application.dataPath)+"/movie.ogv");   

       // Wait for download to complete
       yield www;

       movieTexture = (MovieTexture) www.movie; 
       renderer.material.mainTexture = movieTexture;
       audio.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;

    }
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) for a thorough explanation of how this works. In short `yield` instructs the script to wait at that line until the www object is ready.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It's not enough to just put a file of an appropriate format in a folder. Movie is a resource hence it needs to be treated like all the other resources.

You need to load ad it using `Resources.Load(....)` and then assign the resulting  `MovieTexture` to the object in question.

It would help if you shared a bit more about your loading procedure for these movies.

Comment: Where I'm confused is why my current method worked and loaded fine with a smaller file - I'm not just putting a ogv in a folder and wondering why it won't load without prompting it to - but with a bigger file it freaks out and crashes. Off the top of my head I do not remember my code though, so when I get home tonight I will post it here for you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've edited my main post with the code I have. I cobbled it together while having almost no C# knowledge, so I'm not sure how to use this Resources.Load() function in conjuction with what I have going on now. If you have the time I would love to see how it works, otherwise thank you for the heads up and I can google around to see how it works.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex! I tried to figure out yield some weeks ago but thought I didn't need it at all (again, new here with C#). I'll have free time tomorrow night to try this out and select your answer as the right one :)

Comment: Hey man, so when I plug in those two extra lines, I get the error " a local variable named "www" is already defined in this scope."

Comment: Hey. Sry I didn't realize you had the variable already defined outside of the function. See my edit. Basically you need to remove WWW. Since you already defined the www variable outside of the function, you can't define it again.

Comment: Remove www as in literally, so it's just a "yield;" line?

After erroring last night, I continued to Google and found several threads of people saying that trying to yield for a www specifically could cause problems. Thank you for your continued help by the way! This thing has stopped my project in its tracks for weeks now and it's great that I should be able to get it up and running soon.